# Missing comment and subject in mail

Tags: php, email

I am doing contact form as a school project. I found out that it only sends mail, but there is no subject and comment. Can you please help me?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['jmeno'])) {
    if (!isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['koment']) || $_POST['jmeno'] = "" || $_POST['email'] = "" || $_POST['koment'] = "") {
        die("Nastala chyba, musíte vyplnit všechny pole! Požadavek nebyl odeslán.");
    } else {
        mail('something@mail.com', $_POST['email'], $_POST['koment']);
        echo '<span style="text-align:center;color:green;font-size:30px;"> Připomínka odeslána</span>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: what `print_r($_POST)` says before `mail()` function call? and which parameter is your subject and your mail body? documentation says following order: `mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message )`

Comment: Hello, email is used as an object and koment is my message. I think I have that function correct, but for some reason comment and subject are not part of mail. It works only when it is just written like this "something", but otherwise not.

Answer (score -1):

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
 bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] );
```

I have created a function

```
 mails($EmailTo, $Subject, $Message, $EmailFrom, $ReplyTo);
```

to send email by passing the parameters which can send contents in the HTML format. You can add a HTML table in `$Message` to view the email in a nice format.

```
<?php
// email alerts
function mails($EmailTo, $Subject, $Message, $EmailFrom, $ReplyTo='') 
{
    $To   = $EmailTo;
    $Body = $Message;
    $Headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n"; 
    $Headers .= "From: $EmailFrom \r\n";
    $Headers .= "Reply-To: $ReplyTo \r\n";
    $Headers .= "Content-type: text/html;  charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n"; 

    $MailSent = mail($To, $Subject, $Body, $Headers);
    return $MailSent;
}
```

**Edited:**

```
if (isset($_POST['jmeno'])) 
{
    if (!isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['koment']) || $_POST['jmeno'] == "" || $_POST['email'] == "" || $_POST['koment'] == "") 
    {
        die("Nastala chyba, musíte vyplnit všechny pole! Požadavek nebyl odeslán.");
    } 
    else 
    {
        $EmailFrom = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
        $ReplyTo   = $EmailFrom;
        $EmailTo   = 'something@mail.com';
        $Subject   = 'Subject Here';
        $Comment   = isset($_POST['koment']) ? nl2br($_POST['koment']) : '';

        $Message   = '
        Hi, <br />

        You have recieved a new message.<br /><br />

        <table border="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="100px">Email From :</td><td align="left" valign="top" width="200px">'.$EmailFrom.'</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">Koment :</td><td align="left" valign="top">'.$Comment.'</td>
        </tr>
        </table>';

        $MailSent = mails($EmailTo, $Subject, $Message, $EmailFrom, $ReplyTo);

        if ($MailSent)
        echo '<span style="text-align:center;color:green;font-size:30px;"> Připomínka odeslána</span>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please comment while down vote, it helps to improve the code or identify the issue in the answer

Comment: Hello, still won´t receive any subject and message.

Comment: Edited the code above, there were assignment opertaor used instead comparison operator. whats the output shows?

Comment: The email only send if: email, koment, jmeno are not empty. make sure these fields are not empty. Note: dont understand why 'jmeno' for? Is this the button name?

Answer (score -2):

Here is a working example of sending an email with extra headers using php mail() function.

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Have a look at the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) where you will find more examples of adding subject as well as additional headers to your emails.

Your code, edited for example:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['jmeno'])) 
{
    if (!isset($_POST['email']) || 
        !isset($_POST['koment']) || 
        $_POST['jmeno'] = "" || 
        $_POST['email'] = "" || 
        $_POST['koment'] = "") 
        {
        die("Nastala chyba, musíte vyplnit všechny pole! Požadavek nebyl odeslán.");
    } 
    else 
    {
        $headers = 'From: something@mail.com' . "\r\n" .
                   'Reply-To: something@mail.com';

        if( mail($_POST['email'], 'SUBJECT HERE', $_POST['koment'], $headers) )
        {
            echo '<span style="text-align:center;color:green;font-size:30px;"> Připomínka odeslána</span>';         
        } else {
            echo 'Email error message';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @Quentin good point. The answer now has appended example code as proposed in SO meta. I cannot se how the answer deserves minus credits though as it will surely help solve the issue for Restr.

Comment: Yes, it works, but only because it won´t receive any informations from my form. I don´t know why, but it just does not sends subject and comment.

Comment: @Restr Just to be clear, your code seems to be missing the subject in mail(). See my updated answer for an edited example.